# How do we define a sequence from a function?

Tags: sequences-and-series

When is a recursive sequence, generated by "a" belonging to a closed interval H and a function f ,well defined and why??

Comment: Do we need to have f(H) subset of H ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f:X\rightarrow X$ and $a \in X$, the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ defined by $a_0 = a$ and $a_n = f(a_{n-1})$ is always well-defined.

Now, if you have $a \in H \subset X$ and you would like $a_n \in H$ for all $n$, that is a different story. In this case, a sufficient condition is that $f(x) \in H$ for all $x \in H$ (stated more succinctly, $f(H)\subset H$).

Moreover, if $H$ is a *complete metric space* and $f$ is a *contraction*, the sequence $(a_n)_n$ is [guaranteed to admit a limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) $a^{\star}$ satisfying $f(a^{\star})=a^{\star}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, additional question yet: does $f$ always need to have same initial and final sets?

Comment: Suppose $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $x\in X$. Then $f(x)$ is not necessarily in $X$, and hence $f(f(x))$ may not be defined.